# Upgraded to ruby on rails 3.2 and now getting uninitialized constant Rake::DSL error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems

Everything was working fine before upgrading but now I can't run rake tasks.. any idea if this is something to do with rake 0.9.2.2?

I don't understand why this problem sometimes occurs.

```
[gh (master)]$ bundle list | grep rake
  * rake (0.9.2.2)
[gh (master)]$ gem list | grep rake
rake (0.9.2.2, 0.8.7)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways.. I preferred the 
**1st way:**

I typed this from home directory in terminal:

```
nano .bash_profile
```

and pasted this in the file:

```
   bundle_commands="rake spec rspec cucumber cap watchr rails rackup"

    function run_bundler_cmd () {
        if [ -r ./Gemfile ]; then
            bundle exec $@
        else
            $@
        fi
    }

    for cmd in $bundle_commands
    do
        alias $cmd="run_bundler_cmd $cmd"
    done
```

then typed:

```
source ~/.bash_profile or restart terminal
```

**2nd way.**

I typed this from home directory in terminal:

```
nano .bashrc <br />
nano .bash_profile <br />
```

copied and pasted this into the files:

```
# fix for ruby on rails rake issue
alias bi="bundle install --binstubs=.bin"
export PATH="./.bin:$PATH"
```

then closed terminal and re-opened to get everything working.

I also added .bin to my gitignore file.

Answer (score 1):

I'll take an educated guess and say that rails 3.2 requires a different version of rake from rails 3.1

If you run `bundle exec rake` instead of just rake then it will use the version specified in your current Gemfile.lock

If that doesn't work, please post the contents of :

```
bundle list | grep rake
```

And

```
gem list | grep rake
```

Comment: Tested it on rake routes and it now works, but rake routes alone doesn't. I've posted you're request above.